# Amazon EC2 instance:Server refused our key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Amazon EC2 instance: Server refused our key while using amazon server as well as Ubuntu server.please help me how to resolve this issue. i am very new to AWS services..i have strucked from 2 days ..please help me get out this.

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit this file in the ubuntu server

cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
...
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting ! Try

```
$chmod 400 key.pem
```

and then try to ssh using 
$ ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@IPAddress

Another mistake which people generally make is using right user. If your server is ubuntu; then user name should be ubuntu; else try user ec2-user

Answer (score 0):

If you are re-using a connection configuration in putty you were using previously to connect to a different ec2 instance of a different type, make sure you change the name (located in Connection -> Data) to `ubuntu`